# Java Arcsin not outputting correct value

Tags: java

`arcsin` is outputting the wrong answer while `sin` works as intended and I have no idea why this is happening

```
if (func.equals("sqrt")) x = Math.sqrt(x);
else if (func.equals("sin")) x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("arcsin")) x = Math.asin(Math.toRadians(x));
else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
```

Comment: The input to arc sin isn't an angle.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Math.toRadians` as input to arcsin, it isn't expecting an angle, but a number between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to arc sin isn't an angle, so don't convert `x` to radians first.

It's hard to know exactly what you intend, but perhaps you mean:

```
x = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(x));
```